# Number of cycles in a grid such that each cycle traverse all the lines

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

**Definition:** An edge-component is a sequence of some consecutive collinear-segments.

Consider an $n \times n$ grid-like arrangement of $2n$ lines. Is there any idea about the number of simple cycles with exactly $2n$ edge-components such that each line in the grid contains exactly one edge-component of the cycle? In other words, the cycles should traverse all the lines.
A simple cycle is a cycle which passes through the nodes exactly once.

In the picture you can see a $7\times7$ grid-like arrangement and a desired 14-cycle.
[image]

Any hint or observation is helpful.

Comment: How about non-simple? If you allow intersections, it might be easier...and you'll also need to know how many 'units' the path traverses.

Comment: Then the problem is rather easy, and I know the solution and the exact number. Removing the intersections is worthy.

Answer (score 1):

The structures you want to count are constrained [self-avoiding lattice polygons](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingPolygon.html). This [paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0811/0811.4415v1.pdf) describes some exactly solved models; it is from this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402099266), which is the standard reference on these types of problems.

Normally lattice polygons are counted based on their perimeter or area, but your constraint naturally suggests
counting these $2n$-gons by the number of vertices/edges as you propose.

If the tours needn’t be self-avoiding, then there are $\frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$ of them; permute the rows and columns, and divide by $2n$ because neither the start-point nor the orientation is relevant.

The first six terms ($n=2\;\:..\: 7$) are $1, 4, 26, 240, 2918, 44424$. Here are the $26$ octagons:

[image: octagons]

This sequence is now [A203935](http://oeis.org/A203935) in OEIS; the [superseeker](https://oeis.org/ol.html) failed to return any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?  As there are $n$ vertical lines and $n$ horizontal lines, the circuit will certainly have at least $2n$ segments.  Proving that you can always do it with $2n$ segments is not difficult:  just imagine a staircase.  Are you looking for how many different circuits are possible?  Are rotation and reflection considered?

Comment: Absolutely! How many different circuits of length $2n$ are in the grid. This makes the problem rather hard. But because of the well shaped appearance of the grid, I want to see if any one has any suggestion for counting these circuits or an upper/lower bound for them. Although $(n-1)!$ is known as a lower bound.

Comment: My first approach would be to calculate the small values and feed the list to http://oeis.org/.  n=1 yields 1 (the square), n=2 gives 4 (cut a corner out of the square).  If you get 3 and 4 that may be enough.

Comment: No dear. for $n=2$ you have only one circuit, why 4? 
$n=2$ the grid has 4 intersection points and 4 bounded segments, and then it has just one cycle.

Comment: Exactly. For $2n=8$ there are 26 different cycles and for $2n=10$ there are 240 different cycles. And...

Comment: @Losy:  I misread your $n$ and you are right.  For $n=2$ there is only one cycle.  For $n=3$ there are four (cut one corner out of the square.)  This is a correction to a comment that should be above yours.  I put 4,26,240 into OEIS and only found two, neither of which seems right.  I would write a program to get the next two or three, then see if it fits a polynomial.

Comment: WooooW! thanks a lot... I hope it works.

Comment: @Ross: Technically...an infinite number of polynomials would fit your data... :P

Comment: @El'endia Starman:  I know that, but they are usually low degree.  And polynomials that decrease are out.  No guarantees, but it often works.

Comment: @Ross: True. Also, I had never thought about eliminating decreasing polynomials...